# Oracle ASM : Alter asm_diskstring when ASM Instance is Down,

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-asm

I am beginner for Oracle ASM
I know we can alter asm_diskstring with following ways

1. SqlPlus
2. ASMCA

but these requires +ASM to be UP and running. Is there way to set asm_diskstring when +ASM instance is down ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can create pfile to set `asm_diskstring`.

```
$ vi asmpfile.ora
instance_type=asm
asm_diskstring=path_to_asmdisks
```

Then can start asm instance using this pfile and later can create spfile from pfile.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with simply "alter system set asm_diskstring='whatever' scope=both;"

Comment: Is there any way to fire "alter system set_diskstring='whatever' scope=both;' when asm is down ?

Comment: In order to issue ANY sql statement to ANY instance - db or asm - the instance has to be at least STARTED.  In the case of ASM instances, that means either started  or mounted.  Since the parm is dynamic and takes effect immediately, why would you need/want the instance to be down?